# jquery onclick with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Имеется какая то кнопка

```
<button id="commonId"></button>
```

Как мне сделать событие onclick и передать параметры в функцию Jquery, которая ссылается на это событие?

Answer (score 0):

Эм, [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)?

```js
$('#commonId').on('click', function(e, data){
  console.info('Click', data);
});

$('#commonId').trigger('click', ['YourData']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="commonId">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: а чтобы данные доставались с кнопки как то так: <button param1="A">

Comment: @ImZ, в смысле? Где доставались - в событии или обработчике? Да и `$(...).attr('param1')` никто не отменял.